# Values not passing properly?

Tags: c++, object

I've been working on this project for a while, it's a new language for me but I had a partner with experience who kinda ditched me. Anyways, right now I'm having trouble with getting the text from one object to another. I instantiate an object in the game class, then try to get it and save it to another object in the main class but when I get the object it's empty! I don't know what's going on here and I just can't seem to figure it out.

but the part that isn't working is in the display method when I try to draw the questions text:

```
drawText((WinWidth/2)-225, (WinHeight/2) - 90, curQuestion.question.c_str());
```

curQuestion is created at the top but instantiated in the mouse method:

```
curQuestion = g.getQuestion(col,row);
```

and here's the game class (which is in Cc.h)

```
class Game {
public:
    Game(bool);
    void initQuestions();
    Question getQuestion(int, int);
    string getQuestionText(int, int);

private:
    Question questions[5][5];
};

Game::Game(bool m)
{
    mp = m;
    initQuestions();
}

void Game::initQuestions()
{
    bool hasDouble = false;
    srand( time(NULL));
    int blarg = rand() % 25 + 1;
    fstream questionFile;
    questionFile.open("questions.txt", ifstream::in);
    int cur = 0;
    for(int c = 0; c < 5; c++)
    {
        for(int r = 0; r < 5; r++)
        {
            char * q = new char[256];
            char * a = new char[256];
            questionFile.getline(q,256);
            questionFile.getline(a,256);
            questions[c][r] = Question(c,r, false, q, a);
            cout << questions[c][r].question.c_str() << questions[c][r].answer.c_str();
        }
    }
    questionFile.close();
}

Question Game::getQuestion(int c, int r)
{
    return questions[c][r];
}

string Game::getQuestionText(int c, int r)
{
    return questions[c][r].question;
}
```

Note: the cout called in the game method does return exactly what it should!

Question class:

```
class Question {
public:
    int col;
    int row;
    bool dailyDouble;
    string question;
    string answer;
    int value;
    Question();
    Question(int, int, bool, string, string);
    bool checkAnswer(string);
    string getQuestion();
};

Question::Question() { }

Question::Question(int c, int r, bool d,string q, string a)
{
    col = c; row = r; dailyDouble = d; question = q, answer = a;
    cout << "TEST> Q: " << question << ", A: " << answer << endl;
    if(d)
        value = r * 200 * 2;
    else
        value = r * 200;
}

bool Question::checkAnswer(string answer)
{
    if(answer.find("What is") && answer.find(answer))
        return true;
    return false;
}

string Question::getQuestion() {
    return question;
}
```

I really can't understand what's going wrong here, any help is greatly appreciated. I hope that once I figure out what's going wrong here I'll be able to finish on my own!

Comment: Way.Too.Much.Code. Always remember [this](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sure if someone trying to help would need it all.. wanted to be on the safe side. I'll cut it down.

Comment: @Java: We only need the information where the error is. Everything else only distracts. :)

Comment: @Java: The best would be to bring the program down to one little compilable example. Look at the website I linked in my first comment. While you do, I'll try to get something out of your reduced code. :)

Comment: Okay, one extra thing: What exactly in the display code doesn't work? What is the output you expect? What is the output you get?

Comment: The problem is related to Question class. Please post the code of class Question.

Comment: @user: I think the `Question` class is the on he [posted here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029312/invalid-null-pointer-in-xstring).

Comment: You most probably defined a copy constructor for question that is not copying members. Does getQuestionText returns the question string ok ? Well it seems to be related to the operator= from the other question Xeo posted.

Comment: @Xeo it returns an empty string and I'm expecting a string that contains the question loaded into it from the initQuestions() In game  @Eric no it doesn't seem to be returning the question string

Comment: @ildjarn: I appreciate your stubborness. xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code on my computer, it seems that both the Question class and the Game class is correct, I also tried the Game::getQuestion() and the Game::getQuestionText() method, it's all correct, and returns the proper value.

By the way, there are no pointer members in the Question Class and the Game Class, so there is no need to write a copy constructor and a operator=() overload method.

Maybe you can check if the col and row you passed in g.getQuestion(col,row) is right or not.

Sorry have to post an answer here, cause I don't know how to add a comment to your question.

wish this will help.

Comment: okay.. I still can't get it working :/ this is getting really frustrating. I checked that again and it's giving the right column and row

Comment: @JavaJosh94 can you send me your whole solution? I'm very curious. My Email is uewing AT 126.com

Comment: sorry, I just now got back on and noticed this. I completely took out the game class and the question class then just put a couple arrays into the main class that stored the questions and answers. It's not very efficient but it worked :P

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Game::getQuestion(int c, int r) is returning a Question class by value.  I don't think you want to be doing this, most likely you want 'curQuestion' to be a pointer (Question*) and have getQuestion also return a pointer to a Question.

This way the questions will be stored in the game class and just temporally referenced by whatever calls getQuestion.